# How to properly estimate a change in slope across a cutoff value

Tags: regression, stata, regression-discontinuity

Imagine that you want to estimate whether the slope between y and x changes after a cutoff value. Assume that the cutoff is not at x = 0 but at some arbitrary point c.

I could estimate this two different ways:
$$ Y = \beta_1 \cdot X + \beta_2 \cdot [(X - c)\times 1[X > c]] $$
or
$$ Y = \beta_1 \cdot X + \beta_2 \cdot [X \times 1[X > c]] + \beta_3 \cdot 1[X > c].  $$
Basically, you either need to rescale second x variable or all for a level shift at $c$.

My problem is that estimating these two specifications yields numerically different results and standard errors. Is one of the correct? Or are they effectively the same but there are just some numerical differences.

Some example code in stata below:

```
* Parameters
clear all 
local numberObs 1000
local slopePre 1
local slopePost_change 0
local jump 0
local xStart 0
local xEnd 1
local cutoff .5

* Simulate data
set obs `numberObs'
gen x = runiform()*(`xEnd'-`xStart')+`xStart'
gen postCutoff = x >= `cutoff'
gen y = `slopePre'*x + `slopePost_change'*postCutoff*(x - `cutoff') + `jump' + rnormal()/4

* Estimating
gen xPost = x*postCutoff

* Option 1: separate intercepts
reg y x xPost postCutoff


* Option 2: rescaling
replace xPost = x - `cutoff' if postCutoff == 1 
reg y x xPost
```

Comment: The second model allows for a zero-order discontinuity (vertical jump) in X.  I've never seen a process that would do that unless X=time.  Stick with the first model unless you know there is such a discontinuity (not from looking at the data).  Note that the linear spline with one knot that you are fitting is very dependent on $c$ and has a discontinuity in the first derivative, which we seldom see in nature.  Hence the popularity of cubic splines.